# Python 3 Writing Input file in reverse order to output file

Tags: file, python-3.x, reverse

I have tried searching, but I havent found exactly what I need. I am using python 3, and I need help writing a text file in reverse order to a different output file.

**So this would be the input file**

```
Hey, I am Fred

Fred, what's up

Fred fred fred
```

**And this would be the output file**

```
Fred fred fred

Fred, what's up

Hey, I am Fred
```

If anyone has any insight into how to accomplish I would really appreciate it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open (input_file_name) as fi, open(output_file_name, 'w') as fo:
    fo.writelines(reversed(fi.readlines()))
```

If input_file is malformed (last line doesn't end with '\n') you may use a quick (maybe not too efficient) hack:

```
with open ('c:\\temp\\input_file') as fi, open('c:\\temp\\output_file', 'w') as fo:
    fo.write('\n'.join(reversed(fi.read().splitlines())))
```

Comment: Having a 't' flag when opening helps clarifying that it's text you get. Otherwise good.

Comment: Hey, this code almost works, but is doing something strange. Lets say the lines of the code are 1, new line 2, new line 3. The output file will contain 32, newline 1       The same goes for if the lines of code are say Fred, new line Tiger, new line Ant. The output file will contain AntTiger, newline Fred

Comment: @user1797763, there's nothing strange, it's a simple, not foolproof solution that doesn't handle malformed text files. Updated the answer for your case.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, appreciate it.